# While installing Web3js dependency it is showing node-gyp issue

Tags: npm, web3js, npm-scripts, node-gyp

I am trying to install a web3js dependency for my project. But there is an issue coming up with `node-gyp`.

Below is the error log for that"

```
> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall D:\Learning\BlockChain Project\Inbox\node_modules\scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js


> scrypt@6.0.3 install D:\Learning\BlockChain Project\Inbox\node_modules\scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\Learning\BlockChain Project\Inbox\node_modules\scrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: unable to verify the first certificate
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1049:34)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:631:8)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Learning\BlockChain Project\Inbox\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-19T18_07_03_360Z-debug.log
```

Comment: It points you to C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-19T18_07_03_360Z-debug.log, it would be good to see the relevant aspects of that also.

Comment: since web3 is an ethereum tool you may want to ask here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

install `windows-build-tools` before installing `web3` and its dependencies

```
    npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

reference: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the above windows-build-tools but had to install with `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools --vs2015` as the newer versions of this tool are going to not compile the web3 utils correctly with the `node-gyp` dependency. I wrangled this one for a while after uninstalling an old install of Visual Studio 2015 a couple of weeks ago.